Understanding cancellation costs for fare
I am looking to book some flights, which I need to do before applying for a visa.  If the visa is refused then I need to cancel the flights and want to understand exactly how much I will be refunded.  I find this website quite confusing, however the below screenshot shows the refund terms:

I also added a copy of the fare conditions which is exactly the same for inbound and outbound: https://pastebin.com/WNHUCT2h
How much will I be refunded if I cancel? I'm confused how many times I need to add up the £200 to get the cancellation cost.

I understand that it is £200 in case you have one fare for the round trip, and £400 in case you have a separate fare for each way. To be sure you should contact the airline directly. However, the best thing for you seems to be a Flex Plus ticket since it's fully refundable and about the same price.

Check first whether this is actually required (it isn't for a UK visa for instance).

Yes it's definitely needed since one traveller does not have a British passport.
